# Overflow hidden setting is not working in IE 11, Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x397cL72/)  
in which i am expecting the description is actually hides the overflown content and shows text only the allocated width percentage.(in this case 17%).
I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 version for CSS styling.
I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped mytable" rules="all" id="gvTimeEntries" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr style="color:White;background-color:#00A4E4;font-weight:bold;">
            <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Project</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Sub-Project</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Task</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Description</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Mon</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Tue</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Wed</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Thu</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Fri</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Sat</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Sun</th>
            <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblProject" title="Rater Onboarding &amp; Support" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum n</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblSubProject" title="Rater Onboarding and Version Release " style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus  </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblTask" title="Design &amp; Development" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">Sample</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblComment" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultrices ligula ut posuere ultrices. Ut facilisis mauris tortor, vitae molestie lorem bibendum eget. Etiam vehicula maximus dui et auctor. Morbi eget pulvinar sapien. Vivamus mi lorem, congue id porta in, interdum vitae lectus. Fusce id viverra justo, quis finibus metus. Ut feugiat consequat metus at volutpat. Phasellus mi leo, vulputate id tortor eu, accumsan eleifend lectus. Nam lobortis feugiat ligula, eget iaculis risus tristique et. Cras at nunc orci. Sed volutpat magna vel nunc dignissim sodales. Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum nec, sollicitudin sit amet dui. Etiam dapibus, lacus non facilisis ullamcorper, quam arcu tempus risus, nec porta orci purus vel lectus. Maecenas nec molestie nisl. Sed id velit ac sapien finibus blandit. In non sed.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultrices ligula ut posuere ultrices. Ut facilisis mauris tortor, vitae molestie lorem bibendum eget. Etiam vehicula maximus dui et auctor. Morbi eget pulvinar sapien. Vivamus mi lorem, congue id porta in, interdum vitae lectus. Fusce id viverra justo, quis finibus metus. Ut feugiat consequat metus at volutpat. Phasellus mi leo, vulputate id tortor eu, accumsan eleifend lectus. Nam lobortis feugiat ligula, eget iaculis risus tristique et. Cras at nunc orci. Sed volutpat magna vel nunc dignissim sodales. Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum nec, sollicitudin sit amet dui. Etiam dapibus, lacus non facilisis ullamcorper, quam arcu tempus risus, nec porta orci purus vel lectus. Maecenas nec molestie nisl. Sed id velit ac sapien finibus blandit. In non sed.</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblMon" class="inputMonday">7</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblTue" class="inputTuesday">6</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblWed" class="inputWednesday">4</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblThu" class="inputThursday">7</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <span id="lblFri" class="inputFriday">7</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                    <span id="lblSat" class="inputSaturday">0</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                    <span id="lblSun" class="inputSunday">0</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" align="center">
                <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 100%;">
                    <span id="lblTotalHours" class="inputTotalRow">31</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the table cell will always attempt to fit all the content possible into its dimensions, ignoring any declaration of widths, unless you fix its layout. This is as simple as declaring `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` element in question, i.e.:

```
.mytable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;

    /* Fix layout */
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Here is a working example of your code (or see the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/x397cL72/2/). You might want to view it in full for a better effect:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f3f3f4;
}

body,
textarea,
* {
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.mytable th,
.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.mytable th {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.overflowHidden {
  /*display: inline-grid;
    display: -ms-inline-grid;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped mytable" rules="all" id="gvTimeEntries" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#00A4E4;font-weight:bold;">
      <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Project</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Sub-Project</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Task</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden" scope="col" style="width:17%;">Description</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Mon</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Tue</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Wed</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Thu</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Fri</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Sat</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Sun</th>
      <th class="overflowHidden headerOverflowNormal" scope="col" style="width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblProject" title="Rater Onboarding &amp; Support" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum n</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblSubProject" title="Rater Onboarding and Version Release " style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus  </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblTask" title="Design &amp; Development" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">Sample</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:17%;">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblComment" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultrices ligula ut posuere ultrices. Ut facilisis mauris tortor, vitae molestie lorem bibendum eget. Etiam vehicula maximus dui et auctor. Morbi eget pulvinar sapien. Vivamus mi lorem, congue id porta in, interdum vitae lectus. Fusce id viverra justo, quis finibus metus. Ut feugiat consequat metus at volutpat. Phasellus mi leo, vulputate id tortor eu, accumsan eleifend lectus. Nam lobortis feugiat ligula, eget iaculis risus tristique et. Cras at nunc orci. Sed volutpat magna vel nunc dignissim sodales. Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum nec, sollicitudin sit amet dui. Etiam dapibus, lacus non facilisis ullamcorper, quam arcu tempus risus, nec porta orci purus vel lectus. Maecenas nec molestie nisl. Sed id velit ac sapien finibus blandit. In non sed.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ultrices ligula ut posuere ultrices. Ut facilisis mauris tortor, vitae molestie lorem bibendum eget. Etiam vehicula maximus dui et auctor. Morbi eget pulvinar sapien. Vivamus mi lorem, congue id porta in, interdum vitae lectus. Fusce id viverra justo, quis finibus metus. Ut feugiat consequat metus at volutpat. Phasellus mi leo, vulputate id tortor eu, accumsan eleifend lectus. Nam lobortis feugiat ligula, eget iaculis risus tristique et. Cras at nunc orci. Sed volutpat magna vel nunc dignissim sodales. Maecenas elit ex, feugiat vel fermentum nec, sollicitudin sit amet dui. Etiam dapibus, lacus non facilisis ullamcorper, quam arcu tempus risus, nec porta orci purus vel lectus. Maecenas nec molestie nisl. Sed id velit ac sapien finibus blandit. In non sed.</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblMon" class="inputMonday">7</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblTue" class="inputTuesday">6</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblWed" class="inputWednesday">4</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblThu" class="inputThursday">7</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
          <span id="lblFri" class="inputFriday">7</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
          <span id="lblSat" class="inputSaturday">0</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" valign="top" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
          <span id="lblSun" class="inputSunday">0</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowHidden" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;width:4%;" align="center">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 100%;">
          <span id="lblTotalHours" class="inputTotalRow">31</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks for the quick answer, 
I didn't know about table-layout earlier, now i will read about it.